# Flapper News ui-view cannot display html file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bower, mean-stack

I'm doing a tutorial from https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack called flapper news. I have completed the tutorial and the system work fine. But, I was thinking doing an inline template in a single file is not a good practice specially if you're doing a big project. So I tried to separate those templates into files(.html). Unfortunately the html file cannot be displayed in the ui-view. There was no error in the console nor the server. I tried to change my index.ejs file in the view folder into the public folder and rename it to index.html. Still not working.
Here is my index.html:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Flapper News</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/angularapp.js"></script>
    <style>
    .glyphicon-thumbs-up {
        cursor: pointer
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="flapperNews">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default pull-right" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li ng-show="isLoggedIn()"><a>{{ currentUser() }}</a></li>
      <li ng-show="isLoggedIn()"><a href="" ng-click="logOut()">Log Out</a></li>
      <li ng-hide="isLoggedIn()"><a href="/#/login">Log In</a></li>
      <li ng-hide="isLoggedIn()"><a href="/#/register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <ui-view></ui-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is one of the html file in the same public folder(home.html):

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-upvotes'">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span> {{post.upvotes}}
        <span ng-show="post.author">  posted by <a>{{post.author}}</a> |
            </span>
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
        <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
        {{post.title}}
        </a>
        <span ng-hide="post.link">
            {{post.title}}
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
            <a href="#/posts/{{post._id}}">Comments</a>
            </span>
    </div>
    <form ng-submit="addPost()" ng-show="isLoggedIn()" style="margin-top:30px;">
        <div ng-hide="isLoggedIn()">
            <h3>You need to <a href="/#/login">Log In</a> or <a href="/#/register">Register</a> before you can add a post.</h3>
        </div>
        <h3>Add a new post</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Link" ng-model="link"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </form>
</script>
```

public/javascripts/angularApp.js:

```js
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);

app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    postPromise: [
                        'posts',
                        function(posts) {
                            return posts.getAll();
                        }
                    ]
                }
            })
            .state('posts', {
                url: '/posts/{id}',
                templateUrl: '/posts.html',
                controller: 'PostsCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    post: [
                        '$stateParams',
                        'posts',
                        function($stateParams, posts) {
                            return posts.get($stateParams.id);
                        }
                    ]
                }
            })
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: '/login.html',
                controller: 'AuthCtrl',
                onEnter: ['$state', 'auth', function($state, auth) {
                    if (auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                        $state.go('home');
                    }
                }]
            })
            .state('register', {
                url: '/register',
                templateUrl: '/register.html',
                controller: 'AuthCtrl',
                onEnter: ['$state', 'auth', function($state, auth) {
                    if (auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                        $state.go('home');
                    }
                }]
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    }
]);
```

fyi, the ".state('home', { url:" was ".state('home', { url: '/home'" but it show an error so I change it to "url: '/'" and the error was gone. But still the ui-view cannot display the templates.

This is the output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvnsa.png)

Anyone has any idea on how to solve this? Does **bower** has anything to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the script tag once you have the template on the separate file. Remove it and it should works. You can just use the path of the file for the `templateURL` then

Sometimes you will something like this just like you have,

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html">
   ... some template stuff
</script>
```

That script tag was actually for having the template on the same file as the main template file, and you can use `templateUrl` with the value of the id attribute just like usual. It will treat the body of the script tag as a file of `template.html` since the value of the id is `template.html`